# RMO 1990 question

Tags: contest-math, euclidean-geometry

Prove that the inradius of a right angled triangle having integer sides is also integral

I tried it and got something like

$r=\frac {(a.b)}{(a+b+c)}$

How to proceed after this.

Comment: Hint:  show that $r=\frac 12\times (a+b-c)$.  Now you just have to deal with the parity.

Comment: @lulu Thanks a lot . I would have upvoted you but for some reason the app is not allowing me to .... Your hint was fabulous. Love it.

Comment: Glad to have helped.  No worries on the upvote.

Comment: Regarding why your question was closed: it's impossible to know where that one single line of your working came from, which makes it harder to help you. See [how to ask a good question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that $$r=\frac{a+b-c}{2}$$
Also, the Pythogorian theorem says $$a^2+b^2=c^2$$
$\textbf{Case 1: }$ If both $a$ and $b$ are even numbers then so is $c$, which implies that $a+b-c$ is also even and $r=\frac{a+b-c}{2}$ is integer.

$\textbf{Case 2: }$ If both $a$ and $b$ are odd numbers then $c$ is even, which implies that $a+b-c$ is also even and $r=\frac{a+b-c}{2}$ is integer.

$\textbf{Case 3: }$ If $a$ is an even and $b$ is an odd number then $c$ is odd, which implies that $a+b-c$ is even and $r=\frac{a+b-c}{2}$ is integer.

$\textbf{Case 4: }$ If $a$ is an odd and $b$ is an even number then $c$ is odd, which implies that $a+b-c$ is even and $r=\frac{a+b-c}{2}$ is integer.

Comment: Thank you for the help

Comment: You're welcome.